# Patterns in binary data sorted with rank indices

Tags: binary-data, pattern-recognition, ranks

I have a sequence of binary data, each row of which has seemingly random bits and associated with an integer value ("*rank*"). When we have a binary datum, we always can calculate the *rank* related to it but not the data *from* it's rank value. For an example, with 32-bit length and sorted by its rank:

```
rank     data
69538    10010110 01010100 00110101 11100000 
57643    10010001 01110001 00111010 11001101
3478     01010001 11001001 10100110 11100011
278      11101000 11100000 00100100 01001000
...
```

My question is how do I find a pattern in the data to reduce the rank? The final goal is to get data which have rank indices smaller than certain threshold value. I thought about a neural network but would there be any better approach? Thank you.

Comment: How is the rank calculated?

Comment: ranks are calculated by series of complex functions including sha256 hash. Inverse from rank to data is impossible (well, almost).